# Rendering with background movie clip isn't working

Tags: compositing-nodes

I've tried rendering a 3d poly spider on top of a movie clip (Which I imported from a sequence of PNGs), but even after a bit of compositing nodes I've copied from another similar question it still doesn't render!

[image: I've got the Movie Clip and Render Layers node connected to an Alpha Over node. That node is connected to a composite node. I took this from a similar question yet to no avail.]

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you enable Properties > Film > Transparent?

Answer (score 1):

The spider has a gray background that hides the image on the layer below. You need to render the spider whit a transparent background and the problem should be solved.

As the picture below.

[image]

If you don't know how to set a transparent background, go to properties editor/render/film/transparent

Eevee

[image]

Cycles

[image]